# Regex (grep) Backward match

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I need a Regex which matches the closed `[A-Za-z_0-9]*\.xml` **before** `ERROR`.

The following input should match **match_me.xml**

1. `ERROR` should be determined.
2. The first `[A-Za-z_0-9]*\.xml` before ERROR should be matched. -> **match_me.xml**

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
>   eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
>   voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
>
> match_not_me.xml
>
> dolores et ea rebum.
>
> **match_me.xml**
>
> Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
>
> **ERROR**
>
> aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
awk 'p && /ERROR/{print p; p==""} /^[A-Za-z_0-9]*\.xml$/{p=$0}' file

match_me.xml
```

1. When a line matches our pattern we store that line in variable `p`
2. When `p` is set and we encounter `ERROR` we print `p` and reset it to blank.

Comment: typo, should be `p=""` and can be simplified I think... `'p && /ERROR/{print p; p=""} ...`

Answer (score 1):

***grep*** (*PCRE*) solution:

```
grep -Poz 'ERROR[\s\S]+?\s\K[A-Za-z_0-9]+\.xml' <(tac file) && echo
```

- `tac file` - concatenate lines of the file in reverse order
- `[\s\S]+?` - matches any character in "non-greedy" manner
- `\K` - ignoring previous match

The output:

```
match_me.xml
```